# RobotFramework adding tests through argument file

Tags: python, robotframework

I am learning robot and creating a testframework. I want to give people an easy way to add more tests.

Is it possible to dynamically create tests based on arguments passed in argument file?

I have all my tests in a .rst file and right now users have to populate the test table , but I want to make it simpler so other people actually use the framework.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to dynamically create tests via an argument file.

It is, however, possible to write a script that reads a data file and generates a suite of tests before running pybot.

Comment: Good idea, thanks.  Is there something you would recommend to keep the robot framework formatting intact while creating the file  (Robot is picky about the spacing in the table). I can manually  count spaces and do this obviously but am wondering if there is a neater solution.